# Round to the next tens in Python

Tags: python, math, rounding, ceil

Is there a way to round always up to the next tens? E.g., `0.000000000003` shall become `0.1`. `0.1244593249234` shall become `0.2` and `0.9x` shall become `1`. Negative numbers are not a thing here.

Is there a built in or do I need to come up with something?

Comment: there is a way to probably come up with something that is not built in

Comment: I could just hardcode it in.. But I thought there might be a handy function, no?

Comment: don't know about any builtins

Comment: @ArcKoor Nope, that rounds to 0, it shall round to the next bigger tens

Comment: Are you only dealing with numbers in the (0, 1) range, or would you also want 123.4567 to become 123.5?

Comment: @Reti43 Only 0, 1 range

Comment: @newbypyth I just realised. You could check out [this](https://kodify.net/python/math/round-decimals/#round-decimal-places-up-in-python), looks like someone already has done what you need.

Comment: import the `math`  module and run the ceiling function, e.g.: `math.ceil(x*10.0)/10.0`. You need to add the multiplication/devision workaround to ceil to the desired digit, since ceil will round up to the nearest integer

Comment: (1) You are rounding to *tenths*, not *tens*.  (2) See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).  You apparently didn't do *any* research before posting your question.

Comment: For range (0,1) the ceil from math will do. You can just use math.ceil(x*10)/10 to round given x always up to the 1st decimal digit.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal and https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.ROUND_CEILING

Comment: Here is a way of doing ```x =  0.1244593249234
print("{:.1f}".format(x+.1))```

Comment: I've reopened this question because isn't a dupe.

Comment: @BuddyBobIII this does not account for when the number is already a tenth for example: `x = 0.2`

Comment: @Matiiss works fine for me... I get .3

Comment: @BuddyBobIII except it is not correct since there is nothing to round

Comment: @Matiiss It works fine. I get .3 with this line. Yes it won't hurt to make an exception for If the float only has 1 decimal point. But that's pointless.

Comment: @BuddyBobIII that is certainly not pointless and it really does not take that much more code

Comment: ... It works leave it

Comment: @BuddyBobIII not to sound rude (hope You don't mind) I improved Your code for that one little exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by multiplying the input `f` to 10, you will map it from `[0, 1]` to `[0, 10]`. Now by getting ceil from this number, you will get an integer number in `[0, 10]` that by dividing it by 10, you will obtain the next ten in `[0, 1]` range as you desire:

```
import math

next_ten = math.ceil(f * 10.0) / 10.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Idk, it's a simple solution. I tested it out for all the options you gave and seems to work properly.

```
x = 0.2
print("{:.1f}".format(x+.1))
```

Comment: This is an important answer.  In most cases, you want to STORE your data in its actual form, and you only want to rounding or truncation when you DISPLAY the data.  Remember that `0.2` cannot be represented exactly in floating point.  It's always going to be an approximation.

Comment: Given `x = 0.26`, this prints `0.4`. I doubt that that's what the OP wants. (And `0.65` produces `0.8`.)

Answer (score 0):

here ya go. this is not built in and probably too excessive but it should work at least, work is done:

```
number = input()

number = number.split('.')
first = int(number[-1][0])

if first == 9:
    number = str(int(number[0]) + 1)
else:
    for digit in number[-1][1:]:
        if digit != '0':
            first += 1
            break

    number = number[0] + '.' + str(first)

print(number)
```